# How do I display a text overlay in the corner of the TTY from a background process?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, tty

I have a shell script which outputs the following text to `stdout` if the battery is lower than a certain percentage.

```
 ________________
| Battery Low!   |
| Please connect |
| to a charger.  |
|________________|
```

Is there a way to print this text to a corner of the screen from a background process while in a `TTY` session in a way where it dissapeares when the screen updates?

[image]

Comment: Sure. Request the cursor position, update your string to include terminal control sequences that move to where you need it to, and then move the cursor back to its old position when done. All of this can be done with control sequences in the terminfo database, which `tput` can look up for you.

Comment: That said, do you have a _more specific_ question? "How do I look up the cursor location?" is specific. "How do I move to a known cursor location?" is also specific. "How do I print a box that looks like what I want?" is combining several such small, specific questions into a larger one that could be argued to be overbroad..

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think you've misunderstood the question. The idea is to have a script running in the background that prints the box above (the plain text one, the image is just an illustration) so that I can get a battery notification if I'm not running an X server. Why would cursor position matter in this case?

Comment: You move the cursor up to where you need it to be to print the box, then back down to where the application expects it to be when you're done so the other application using the terminal doesn't suddenly start printing things in the wrong place. How isn't that relevant to your question? I'm talking about the TTY cursor -- the place where text prints -- not the mouse cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Duffy's ideas, I just coded sth. It seems to work fine, but it does ruin the scrollback history (which seems inevitable). It also paints over TUI programs such as VIM, which is a bug or a feature depending on your point of view.

```
function tty-overlay() {
    local y="${tty_overlay_y:-0}" # use 2 to see it after scrolling
    echo -n "$(
    tput sc # save cursor
    tput cup "$y" 0 # move cursor to Y X
    # print -n '\r' # redundant
    echo -n "$*"
    tput rc # restore cursor
    )" > /dev/tty
}
##
function tty-statusbar-update() {

    tty-overlay "$(date +"%H:%M:%S")                                                                  "
    # @warn ruins the scrollback buffer though
}

function tty-statusbar-update-precmd() {
    tty_overlay_y=0 tty-statusbar-update "$@" &|
}

typeset -aUg precmd_functions
precmd_functions+=tty-statusbar-update-precmd
##
```

You can even run `tty-statusbar-update` in a loop in the background.

[image]

---

Some easier, cleaner alternatives:

- Put a warning in the shell's prompt
- Play a sound
- Change your terminal emulator's theme
- Display an OS notification
- Use the status bar of your terminal emulator or `tmux`

Related:

- https://superuser.com/questions/840526/status-line-in-linux-shell
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/473399/a-status-bar-at-bottom-of-terminal-in-place-of-ps1
- https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/nfckki/status_bar_while_in_bash_shell/

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, but comments don't support multiline content and are ill-suited for lists. And the next person looking to 'print to a TTY' will probably be looking for `echo sth > /dev/tty` anyhow. This question is better phrased as `how do I display a text overlay in the corner of the shell?`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree that this is not an answer. If comments supported multi-line, I'd post it as a comment.

Comment: 1. I might be using a terminal program (e.g. vim) and not see the prompt.
2. Not a bad idea but not really what i'm looking for.
3. Using a `TTY`, not a terminal emulator
4. Same as the above. Don't have an X server running thus can't use `notify-send`
5. Same as #3. Don't use `tmux`.

These are decent ideas but they don't really solve the problem.

Comment: @S9oXavyF I just coded sth using Duffy's ideas. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Looks good at a glance. One note -- `function foo() {` merges POSIX and legacy ksh syntax in a way that isn't compatible with _either_ POSIX sh _or_ legacy ksh. Better to just use `foo() {` with no preceding `function`

Comment: You don't need one big `echo` to make things a single redirection -- or is the idea to cache everything to emit it to the terminal in a single write to reduce the chance of other content being printed at the same time? Unless you're trying to do that, I'd just have a compound command to avoid the subprocess overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is there a way**_ ...
>
> so that I can get a battery notification if I'm not running an X server

Write a virtual terminal multiplexer and create one terminal on the top right left part and in that terminal execute your script and on the rest of the screen run another terminal for user interaction.

Definitely read `tmux` and `screen` source code as it will serve as an inspiration. I guess patching an existing project might be easier then starting over - I suggest to contribute to open-source and implement such "window-change-notify" plugin inside tmux and merge it to the project.

> in a way where it dissapeares when the screen updates?

A terminal multiplexer reacts to the changes and can detect any changes, so within your terminal multiplexer you can implement your own behavior that will react to changes. Typically a change in a terminal is displayed as a "bell or activity marker" of windows (see `man tmux`).

> if the battery is lower than a certain percentage.

Typically people display battery notification and other stuff on status lines in terminal multiplexers, like for example [gpakosz/.tmux](https://github.com/gpakosz/.tmux) does.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Although it sounds overcomplicated. Creating something like that sounds like a lot of work for a battery notification daemon, but i might look into it.